# Access property of object in View from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, view, properties, viewmodel

I have a `TabControl` in my View with multiple `TabItems`. I would like to change the its `IsSelected` property of one of the `TabItems` from my ViewModel.

Here is the xaml code for the View:

```
<TabControl Height="50" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                    <TabItem Name="tiCaptureSetup" >
                        <TabItem.Header>                            
                            <Button Name="btnCaptureSetup"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Width="90"
                                    Height="40"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    ToolTip="Capture Setup"
                                    Content="Capture Setup"
                                    Click="btnCaptureSetup_Click"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CaptureSetupButtonStatus, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    IsDefault="True"
                                    ></Button>
                        </TabItem.Header>
                    </TabItem>
```

Here is the C# code behind in View

```
private void btnCaptureSetup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tiCaptureSetup.IsSelected = true;   //select Capture Setup TabItem

            MenuLSViewModel vm = (MenuLSViewModel)this.DataContext;

            if (vm != null)
            {
                vm.CaptureSetupCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
```

And I would like to change `tiCaptureSetup.IsSelected` from ViewModel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way: Make a property in your ViewModel called something like `IsCaptureSetupSelected` and bind it to the `IsSelected` property of `tiCaptureSetup.`

ViewModel:

```
private bool _IsCaptureSetupSelected;
public bool IsCaptureSetupSelected
{
    get { return _IsCaptureSetupSelected; }
    set
    {
            if (_IsCaptureSetupSelected != value)
            {
                    _IsCaptureSetupSelected = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TabItem Name="tiCaptureSetup" IsSelected="{Binding IsCaptureSetupSelected}">
```

Note that I'm assuming you're using something like MVVMLight with your ViewModel...